Diagonalizing the thermalizing lindblad equation
Consider a harmonic oscillator subjected to the thermalizing Lindblad equation
$$\dot{\rho} = {\bf L}[\rho] = \sum_{\pm} L_{\pm} \rho L_{\pm}^\dagger - \frac{1}{2} \{ L_{\pm}^\dagger L_{\pm}, \rho \}, \ \ \ L_{+} = \sqrt{\gamma n_T} a^\dagger, \ \ L_{-} = \sqrt{\gamma (n_T +1)} a$$
where $n_T = 1/(e^{\omega/T}+1)$ is the Boltzmann distribution and I'm ignoring the Hamiltonian term for simplicity. I am wondering if it is possible to explicitly diagonalize this in the sense of finding a set of solutions ${\bf L}[\rho] = \lambda \rho$.
Here's a simpler case that I'm particularly interested in: let $\rho = \sum_n \rho_n |n\rangle \langle n|$ be some diagonal density matrix. It is easy to check that the Lindblad equation will preserve this form, and we can write the Lindblad equation as a matrix equation
$$\dot{\rho}_n = \Lambda_{n,n'} \rho_{n'}, \ \ \ \Lambda_{n,n'} = -\gamma [n (2 n_T+1) + n_T] \delta_{n,n'} + \gamma n_T n \delta_{n,n'+1} + \gamma(n_T+1)(n+1) \delta_{n,n'-1}.$$
So here, I'd like to know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix $\Lambda$. Of course, one eigenvalue is $\lambda = 0$, with eigenvector $\rho_n = e^{-n \omega/T}/Z$, the thermal state. But is there a way to find the rest of the eigensystem?
Update: for this simpler case, this seems almost definitely possible to do. In matrix notation we have
$\Lambda = \gamma \begin{pmatrix} 
- n_T & n_T+1 & 0  & \cdots \\ 
n_T & -2(2n_T+1) - n_T & 2(n_T+1) &  \\
0 & 2 n_T &  -3(2n_T+1) - n_T &  \\
& \vdots & & \ddots 
 \end{pmatrix}$.
This is a tridiagonal matrix with the same sign for all off-diagonal terms, and so using the similarity transformation given on Wikipedia, we can write this as $\tilde{\Lambda} = D \Lambda D^{-1}$, a real symmetric matrix, i.e., a Hermitian operator. Subtracting an overall constant and rescaling by a constant, you can write this as
$\tilde{\Lambda} = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0  &  & \cdots \\ 
1 & -\alpha & 2  & 0 &   \\
0 & 2 &  -2\alpha  & 3 & 0 \\
&  0 &  3 & -3 \alpha & \\
& \vdots & & & \ddots
 \end{pmatrix}$,
where $\alpha = 2 \cosh(\omega/2T)$. This certainly looks like a diagonalizable Hamiltonian...
